# function to determine the height

Tags: javascript, function, height

Simple question

has the function:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

function calcHeight(el){

    el.each(function(){
        if(maxHeight < el.find('.products-title').outerHeight(true)){
            maxHeight = el.find('.products-title').height();
        }

    });

    el.find('.products-title').css('height',maxHeight);
}

calcHeight($('.mini-products-list > li'));
```

but the record is not found the maximum height,but this function works:

```
$('.mini-products-list > li').each(function(){


    if(maxHeight < $(this).find('.products-title').outerHeight(true)){
        maxHeight = $(this).find('.products-title').height();

    }
});

$('.mini-products-list > li').find('.products-title').css('height',maxHeight);
```

The question is why is this happening and what record is correct using the function?

Comment: why are you not using `this` in that function, you are using `el` there, that could be the reason.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please add the tag to your question.

Comment: This looks like you are using jQuery.  it is certainly not just pure javascript.  please add a tag for the library you are using.  Also you should post an example of the HTML and, preferable, a fiddle (e.g. jsfiddle.net) showing the problem.

Comment: I think @j08691 has it: the `el.find('.products-title')`will only ever refer to the height of the first element.  you shopuld use `$(this)`instead of èl`inside the each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `this` to refer current element in function. There you are referring with `el`, so every time it will just determine for first element.

Use `this` there also like bellow.

```
el.each(function(){
      if(maxHeight < $(this).find('.products-title').outerHeight(true)){
          maxHeight = $(this).find('.products-title').height();
      }
 });
```